# Xamarin SqlServer cant get a connection

Tags: android, sql-server, xamarin, .net-core

I'm building an app with the Entity Framework on Xamarin that lets me compare some data. But when I start my "fetchdata" function, I receive the Error:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 35 - SNI_ERROR_35)Snix_Connect (provider: SNI_PN7, error: 35 - SNI_ERROR_35)
```

I see many posts about Xamarin / Android & that it is not possible to get a connection to a SQL Server. Is there any way to fetch data from a SQL Server with .NET Core on Xamarin?

Comment: you can connect directly to SQL server from a mobile client, it's just a HORRIBLE idea.  Have you checked that your server is reachable from your mobile device, that all the relevant ports are open, that there are no firewall issues, etc?

Comment: Jep, and i have no attention at all to do it on the "old school" way, i downloaded right now SQLApp and it connects..

Answer (score 1):

This is the string I put into SQL_Class folder with Sql_Common.cs
Fill up the brace brackets with actual parameters (removing the brace brakets too).

```
public static string SQL_connection_string = @"data source={server_address};initial catalog={database_name};user id={user_id};password={password};Connect Timeout={seconds}";
```

Then I access whenever I need it from any xamarin code just like we use in our asp.net c#
This works for me on my app without any issues.

```
using (SqlConnection Sql_Connection = new SqlConnection(Sql_Common.saralEHR_connection_string))
```

**But as @Jason mentioned in his first reply, I too would get once again check the security part.** I fexperienced before publishing Package to Google Play, they encrypt the App files with Hash Key Code and then only it gets upload to server

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible (HuurrAYY!):
Im new in .net core, c# and so on and for me it was a hell of a work to get it working..
So here for the other noobs who are seeking for Help:

Guide´s i used:
Building Android Apps with Entity Framework
https://medium.com/@yostane/data-persistence-in-xamarin-using-entity-framework-core-e3a58bdee9d1
https://blog.xamarin.com/building-android-apps-entity-framework/

Scaffolding 
https://cmatskas.com/scaffolding-dbcontext-and-models-with-entityframework-core-2-0-and-the-cli/

How i did it:

1. Build your normal Xamarin app.
2. create new .net solution like in the tutorials (DONT WRITE YOUR Entity Framework CLASSES)
3. create a third solution what has to be a .net core console application
4. Scaffold your DB in your CONSOLE application move all created classes & folders in your "xamarin .net" solution & change the    namespaces
5. Ready to Go!

Side Node: NuGets you need in every solution:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

[EDIT: NuGets you need in every solution]

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this way (working snippet):

```
string connectionString = @"data source={server};initial catalog={database};user id={user};password={password};Connect Timeout=10";
        string databaseTable = "{table name}";
        string selectQuery = String.Format("SELECT count(*) as Orders FROM {0}", databaseTable);
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                //open connection
                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = selectQuery;
                var result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                //check if there is result
                if(result != null)
                {
                    OrdersLabel.Text = result;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            OrdersLabel.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```

It is working fine, but API call more elegant.
I hope it helps.